# Unable to import Packages (Twilio) in a node.js container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, twilio, package.json

I created a dockerfile for  the node container as follows:

FROM node:10
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY  ./package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["node","nodeapp.js"]

The package.json as i understand must contain all the dependencies needed for npm to install

here is the what i wrote in the package.son  file:

```
{
 "name": "docker-twilio-nodejs",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": " This package describes the app and the dependencies",

"author": "",

"main":"nodeapp.js",

"scripts" : {

    "start": "node nodeapp.js"

},

"dependencies": {

    "twilio": "^3.46.0"
}
```

}

However when i build the image and run the app, I get the following error:

**app-node_1    | Error: Cannot find module 'twilio'**

does it mean that the npm failed to find   "twilio": "^3.46.0" in the package.json file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you running the application?  (If you've mounted a volume over your `node_modules` directory, Docker will never update the presumably-user data you've stored there, which means it will ignore changes in `package.json`.)

Comment: Hi David. Thanks a lot it worked. I indeed had a volume mounted  on my working directory something like : \n Volumes: ./python: usr/src/app when i removed it it worked.  can you please elaborate on why it is like that? i'm pretty new to docker. I thaught mounting the volume will always copy the latest state of all the documents that are in my host directory into the container's working directory so if i change something in the package.json file , it will be changed in the container's and then when i'll run the container  the new dependencies will be installed

Comment: When you run the container with volume mounts, the contents of those volumes just replace what was in the image; there is no "reinstall" step.  In particular with `node_modules` in a volume it just keeps using the old version of the modules tree.  I generally recommend removing these `volumes:` entirely (so you're actually running the code in the image), and using a host Node for live development.